# Token renewal operation failed due to timeout|Token Renewal Failed

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-ad-msal

I am using angular 8

below is msal configuration

```
"authority": "",
    "clientID": "",
    "redirectUri": "",
    "protectedResourceMap": [
      [
        "",
        [        
          "api:"        
        
         ]       
      ]
   
    ]



  return this.http.get(url).map(data => {
          return data;
      }, catchError(this.handleError));
```

While calling above api first time geting error
**"Token renewal operation failed due to timeout|Token Renewal Failed"**

but same function i AM calling after sometime of site loaded, it is executing without error.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this similar  [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894632/clientautherror-token-renewal-operation-failed-due-to-timeout-msal-angular/62919952#62919952) and please provide source you are using?

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?